Heuristics for hierarchical clustering with custom linkage function
I made my own custom linkage function for SciPy, and I want to add heuristics.
I cluster json sequences and for example if one cluster is sufficiently big (let’s say 20 Jsons) and the other one is smaller (let’s say 2 jsons) I’d rather not merge them at the current iteration and instead make two distinct clusters.
def lcs_based_clustering(sequences, distance_threshold=0.1, max_cluster_size=10): #Dist Threshold represents the ratio of the size of the clusters I'm willing to accept
    distance_matrix, seq_ids = create_distance_matrix(sequences)
    n = len(seq_ids)
    current_clusters = [{i} for i in range(n)]
    current_sequences = [sequences[seq_id] for seq_id in seq_ids]
    linkage_matrix = []

    cluster_sizes = [1] * n  # Initialize sizes of all clusters with 1

    cluster_id = n  # New cluster IDs after original sequences
    while len(current_clusters) > 1:

        # Closest pair of clusters
        min_distance = float('inf')
        min_i, min_j = -1, -1

        for i in range(len(current_clusters)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(current_clusters)):
                distance = calculate_sequence_distance(current_sequences[i], current_sequences[j])
                if distance < min_distance:
                    min_distance = distance
                    min_i, min_j = i, j

        ratio = cluster_sizes[min_j] / cluster_sizes[min_i] if cluster_sizes[min_i] > cluster_sizes[min_j] else cluster_sizes[min_i] / cluster_sizes[min_j]



        # Merging the closest clusters
        new_cluster = current_clusters[min_i].union(current_clusters[min_j])
        _, new_sequence = lcs(current_sequences[min_i], current_sequences[min_j])

        new_cluster_size = cluster_sizes[min_i] + cluster_sizes[min_j]

        cluster1_id = min(current_clusters[min_i])  # The min is only needed to get the first element of the set (There is only one).
        cluster2_id = min(current_clusters[min_j])
        linkage_matrix.append([cluster1_id, cluster2_id, min_distance, new_cluster_size])

        # Creates new lists, that contain all the clusters that didn't merge at this step and the new one.
        current_clusters = [cluster for k, cluster in enumerate(current_clusters) if k not in [min_i, min_j]]  # list of all clusters that didn't merge
        current_sequences = [seq for k, seq in enumerate(current_sequences) if k not in [min_i, min_j]]
        current_clusters.append(new_cluster)
        current_sequences.append(new_sequence)

        # Update cluster IDs and sizes
        current_clusters[-1] = {cluster_id}  # Here we update the last element of the list, which is the new cluster
        cluster_sizes = [size for k, size in enumerate(cluster_sizes) if k not in [min_i, min_j]]
        cluster_sizes.append(new_cluster_size)

        cluster_id += 1
    return np.array(linkage_matrix)
```

